# Approximate the distribution of the sum of ind. Beta r.v

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, beta-distribution

If $X_i$ has a Beta distribution $\beta(1,K)$.

What is the best approximation for the distribution of $ S=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$, when the $X_{i}$ are independent and $N$ is finite.

Comment: If $N$ is large the Central Limit Theorem applies.

Comment: Duplicate of:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842430/approximate-the-distribution-of-the-sum-of-ind-beta-r-v

Comment: What are the possible values of $K$ and $N$ and how should we interpret "best" in a quantitative way?  "Best" for what purpose?

Comment: let's say $N<10$ and $1<K<30$; I just need an approximation of the distribution of this sum (forget the word "best").

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want better approximations than what you get from the central limit theorem, there is results in a book dedicated exclusively to the  beta distribution:   [Handbook of Beta Distribution and Its Applications (Statistics: A Series of Textbooks and Monographs)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824753968) by  Arjun K. Gupta and  Saralees Nadarajah .

(On the amazon.com website you can search within this book!) Around page 70 there is exact results for the sum of two independent beta distributions, around page 70 they find an approximation by assuming the sum also has an generalized beta distribution, and then equate moments. On page 85 they give approximations for general sums by using the same method, equating moments. Around page 85-87 they give references you can follow up.

Answer (score 4):

Since you cannot share details, we cannot know to what extend you can use transformations of your variables, and still get what you need. For what is worth, a usual transformation here is the following:

$$X_i \sim \beta(1,K) \Rightarrow Z_i=-\ln(1-X_i) \sim \text{Exp}(K)$$

and

$$S_z = \sum_{i=1}^NZ_i \sim \text{Erlang}(N,K)$$

with pdf

$$f_{S_z}(s_z) = \frac {K^NS_z^{N-1}e^{-KS_z}}{(N-1)!}$$

Comment: I need the distribution of this sum to calculate $Pr(1+SINR>\tau)$.     If we use this transformation, we get $f(S_z)$; but I am interested in $f(S_x)$.

Comment: @mat What is SINR?

Comment: SINR is the Signal to Interference plus Noise Ratio (used in wireless communications..)

Answer (score 3):

[CLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem): $(S_n-n\mu)/\sigma\sqrt{n}$ is approximately distribured as $\mathrm{N}(0,1)$ for large $n$.

To determine $\mu$ and $\sigma$ use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Mean) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Variance).

Comment: N is small ( $N<10$)

Comment: What is your application?

Comment: Wireless communications ( sorry i can't go into details)

Comment: For every $n$ you can control the quality of the normal approximation using Berry-Esseen style bounds: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem

Comment: Although you could not have known this until the question was clarified, $N$ is so small and $K$ is potentially large enough that the Berry-Esseen bounds are unlikely to be useful.

Comment: Yep, Bill. Non full disclosure questions are tough...